# I was watching a video on youtube and in that video a sentence was spoken. "This video would be different."

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, usage, modal-verbs, will-would

Why is "would" used in this video. (on 00:00:28)
https://youtu.be/1mHjMNZZvFo

Answer (score 1):

Her grammar is non-standard.

This video **will** be a little different.

also, at a different point, she says:

> The more prepared you **are**, the more successful your interview
> **would** be.

This is also non-standard.

The more prepared you **are**, the more successful your interview **will** be.

The more prepared you **were**, the more successful your interview **would** be.

---

**EDIT** - She speaks with what I judge to be an Indian accent. The rules of Indian English may be different from those of the UK and America.